# Issues with Pulling data from SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, custom-data-attribute

My script was working no problems until i added in a third element into my database:

**sysinfo**

```
SysInfoID CHNo Module Dector GasDetected ServiceID SiteID
1         1    O2     O2     O2          0         1
2         2    Meth   Meth   Meth        0         1
3         4    O2     O2     O2          0         1
```

**php script**

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT j.JobID, j.CompletedBy, u.NameUser, j.SchDate, cu.CustName, 
j.ContractNo, j.VisitNo, s.EqName, si.SiteName, si.SiteContact,
si.SiteAddress,si.SiteCounty, si.SiteTele, j.SiteID, si.SiteEmail, cu.CustEmail
FROM jobs as j
INNER JOIN users as u 
 ON j.AssignedTo = u.UserID
INNER JOIN site as si
 ON j.SiteID = si.SiteID
INNER JOIN customer as cu
 ON j.custID = cu.custID
INNER JOIN systypes as s 
 ON j.SysTypeID  = s.SysTypeID
WHERE j.CompletedBy ='0' 
AND j.AssignedTo='$mytechname'") 
 or die(mysql_error()); 


$count = mysql_num_rows($data);

    $CHNo = array();
    $Location = array();
    $Module = array();
    $Dector = array();
    $GasDetected = array();

echo "<ul id='jlisthead' data-role='listview' data-inset='true' data-theme='a'><li data-role='list-divider'>Available Jobs ($count)</li></ul>";

echo '<ul data-role="listview"  id="jobslist" data-split-icon="plus" data-theme="a" data-split-theme="b" data-inset="true" style="overflow: auto; height:175px; max-height: 175px;">'; 
while( $info = mysql_fetch_array ($data))
    {
    if($info[7] == '8' || $info[7] == '9'){
        echo "<li><a id='ajob' data-id='$info[0]' data-assignedto='$info[2]' data-schdate='$info[3]' data-contractno='$info[5]' data-visitno='$info[6]' data-systype='$info[7]' data-sitename='$info[8]' data-contact='$info[9]' data-address='$info[10]' data-county='$info[11]' data-sitetel='$info[12]' data-siteid='$info[13]' data-siteemail='$info[14]' data-custemail='$info[15]' href='#'>$info[8]</a><a id='add'  data-aid='$info[0]' data-aassignedto='$info[2]' data-aschdate='$info[3]' data-acontractno='$info[5]' data-avisitno='$info[6]' data-asystype='$info[7]' data-asitename='$info[8]' data-acontact='$info[9]' data-aaddress='$info[10]' data-acounty='$info[11]' data-asitetel='$info[12]' data-asiteid='$info[13]' data-asiteemail='$info[14]' data-acustemail='$info[15]'></a></li>";     
    }
    else{
        $data2 = mysql_query("SELECT SysInfoID, CHNo, Location, Module, Dector, GasDetected
                              FROM systeminfo
                              WHERE SiteID = $info[13]")
                                  or die(mysql_error());

        $arrlength=mysql_num_rows($data2);
        while( $info2 = mysql_fetch_array ($data2)){
            for($k =0;$k<$arrlength;$k++){
                $CHNo[$k] = $info2[1];
                $Location[$k] = $info2[2];
                $Module[$k] = $info2[3];
                $Dector[$k] = $info2[4];
                $GasDetected[$k] = $info2[5];
             }
        }
    $dis = "<li><a id='ajob' data-id='$info[0]' data-assignedto='$info[2]' data-schdate='$info[3]' data-contractno='$info[5]' data-visitno='$info[6]' data-systype='$info[7]' data-sitename='$info[8]' data-contact='$info[9]' data-address='$info[10]' data-county='$info[11]' data-sitetel='$info[12]' data-siteid='$info[13]' data-siteemail='$info[14]' data-custemail='$info[15]' href='#'>$info[8]</a><a id='add' data-aid='$info[0]' data-aassignedto='$info[2]' data-aschdate='$info[3]' data-acontractno='$info[5]' data-avisitno='$info[6]' data-asystype='$info[7]' data-asitename='$info[8]' data-acontact='$info[9]' data-aaddress='$info[10]' data-acounty='$info[11]' data-asitetel='$info[12]' data-asiteid='$info[13]' data-asiteemail='$info[14]' data-acustemail='$info[15]' ";

    for($j = 0;$j<$arrlength;$j++){
        $dis .= "data-achno".$j." ='$CHNo[$j]' data-alocation".$j."='$Location[$j]' data-amodule".$j."='$Module[$j]' data-adector".$j."='$Dector[$j]' data-agasdetected".$j."='$GasDetected[$j]'";
    }

    $dis .= "data-achtotal='$arrlength'></a></li>";     

    echo $dis;

    }
    }

echo '</ul>';
```

To explain a little, I want to check to see if the $info[7] element is 8/9 if it is then print out the information in a list. if its not then go do an ADDITIONAL query to get more information from another table (sysinfo) and store multipliable values within my list using the attr data.

The first query i have no issues with, but its when i go to do the additional query thats were it gets messed up. my arrlength is equal to "3" but all the data within the data-attr is the same.

**example**

```
<a id="add" data-aid="1" data-aassignedto="Mark McGuinness" data-aschdate="2014-03-22" data-acontractno="12" data-avisitno="4" data-asystype="3500" data-asitename="Tesco" data-acontact="Ann Jones" data-aaddress="21 Good Street Glasgow G14 4CA" data-acounty="Strathcylde" data-asitetel="1413216545" data-asiteid="1" data-asiteemail="" data-acustemail="admin@tesco.com" 
data-achno0="3" data-alocation0="Side door" data-amodule0="02" data-adector0="02" data-agasdetected0="02" 
data-achno1="3" data-alocation1="Side door" data-amodule1="02" data-adector1="02" data-agasdetected1="02" 
data-achno2="3" data-alocation2="Side door" data-amodule2="02" data-adector2="02" data-agasdetected2="02" data-achtotal="3" title="" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-notext ui-icon-plus ui-btn-b"></a>
```

Please help it was working before i inserted a new row into the database. Thanks in advance.

**Resolved**

removed the for loop within the while loop:

**previous**

```
while( $info2 = mysql_fetch_array ($data2)){
            for($k =0;$k<$arrlength;$k++){
                $CHNo[$k] = $info2[1];
                $Location[$k] = $info2[2];
                $Module[$k] = $info2[3];
                $Dector[$k] = $info2[4];
                $GasDetected[$k] = $info2[5];
             }
        }
```

**!!!Fix!!!!**

```
while( $info2 = mysql_fetch_array ($data2)){

    $CHNo[$k] = $info2[1];
    $Location[$k] = $info2[2];
    $Module[$k] = $info2[3];
    $Dector[$k] = $info2[4];
    $GasDetected[$k] = $info2[5];
    $k++;
                                      }
```

Comment: It's probably more efficient to get the ADDITIONAL info regardless of the result. In other words, just do one query. Also, usual stuff about deprecated methods, sql injection, and prepared statements

Comment: ya thanks, managed to get some output.. it prints 9 in total 'Main doorMain doorMain doorBack doorBack doorBack doorSide doorSide doorSide door' im planning to move to PDO =) could you possibly post an answer on how i could do that.. (free points) =)

Comment: i removed the for loop within the while loop... fixed the issue :)